# Yank trimmed string in tmux copy mode

Tags: terminal, tmux, xclip, xsel

I am trying to yank string without trailing and heading spaces using this keybinding:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi z send-keys -X \
copy-pipe 'sed "s/^[[:blank:]]\+//;s/[[:blank:]]\+$//" | xsel -ib'
```

But it doesn't work, `xsel -ob` outputs string with spaces. So does Ctrl+V in GUI applications. Why? How can I achieve desired functionality?

```
tmux 2.6, set-clipboard off
```

**EDIT**: I've tested my sed expression and it works:

```
igor@igor-ideapad:~$ echo "   hello world    " | sed "s/^[[:blank:]]\+//;s/[[:blank:]]\+$//"
hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra \ before your first + and character classes are an extended regexp feature so you need to use `sed -E` (for BSD sed) or `sed -r` (for GNU sed). I don't know why you have `[[:blank:]` and `\s` but I don't think you need them both.

You can test your regexp with sed from the command line:

```
printf ' abc '|sed -E "s/^[[:blank:]]+//;s/[[:blank:]]+$//"|wc -c
       3
```

Edit: actually I am too used to using EREs and BSD sed, apart from the extra `\s`, OP's original regexp is a valid BRE with GNU sed.

Comment: You are right about extra `s` in the "ending" part of the `sed` expression. But other than that it is correct and should gracefully trim leading spaces, and it does in interactive bash terminal, but not in tmux binding. In `sed` basic expressions, character classes do work, and  `+` should be "escaped" to be interpreted.

Comment: Oh yes, actually you are right for BREs.

Comment: In GNU 'sed' the only difference between basic and extended regular
expressions is in the behavior of a few special characters: '?', '+',
parentheses, braces ('{}'), and '|'.

   With basic (BRE) syntax, these characters do not have special meaning
unless prefixed backslash ('\'); While with extended (ERE) syntax it is
reversed: these characters are special unless they are prefixed with
backslash ('\').

Comment: What exactly are you copying from tmux? Does it end in a newline? That will not be matched by [[:blank:]].

Comment: Yes, but it would be enough for me to trim leading spaces first, then I can go further and improve `sed` expression. Just curious about is it some real issue with `xsel`, `xclip`(which I also tried) and pipes in `tmux` commands, or is it me doing something wrong

Comment: Hmm, I can reproduce this. Strange.

Comment: I think it is not xsel, it does the same with "|cat >/tmp/test". But the command tmux is running looks OK to me.

Comment: The problem is the `\+` somehow, it works if I do use an ERE so I don't need the \. But I can't figure out why, you are using 's so you shouldn't need to escape it for .tmux.conf and I can't see anywhere else tmux will expand escapes.

Comment: Oh wait, I'm stupid. I'm using BSD sed and `\+` in BREs is a GNU sed feature, that's why your expression didn't work for me in the first place. It works for me with GNU sed. So I can't really help you by reproducing. I can suggest a couple of things: try `|cat >tmp/test` instead of xsel and that will rule out xsel. If that still doesn't work, you can run `tmux -Ltest -vv new` to start a new server with logging, then if you search `job_run` in the tmux-server*.log file you will see the command it is actually running - although bear in mind that when it logs the command, it will escape any \s.